# Lambda and list comprehension in this equation

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, split, list-comprehension

I have created a data set as shown below.

```
train  = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,4],'features':[["A","B","C"],["A","D","E"],["C","D","F"]]})
```

When I execute the line below:

```
train['features_t'] = train["features"].apply(lambda x: " ".join(["_".join(i.split(" ")) for i in x]))
```

It yields a nice result.

```
0    A B C
1    A D E
2    C D F
```

However, I am quite curious about the function in the apply. It basically iterates the values in the feature column of the train dataframe. After that it splits A,B,C and joins back without any delimiter. But when I tried to execute step by step, it gives me an error about the split function.

I tried by creating a for loop, then split function and join function,but fails.

```
   for x in train['feature']:
      a = x.split(" ")
    ............................
```

It gives me this

```
    'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

What might be wrong with my understanding of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x is the list of each line

If you print it:

```
for x in train['features']:
    print(x)
```

Result will be:

```
['A', 'B', 'C']
['A', 'D', 'E']
['C', 'D', 'F']
```

You can accomplish the join by using:

```
for x in train['features']:
    a = ''.join(x)
```

Which will print:
ABC
ADE
CDF

Answer (score 1):

There's an extra level of looping that you've overlooked because it's don't automatically by the `apply` call on the DataFrame. The `lambda` function gets called on the values which are lists of strings. So the list comprehension is iterating over those strings (e.g. `'A'`, then `'B'`, then `'C'`). The `split` method gets called on the strings.

In your explicit loop version, you're trying to call `split` on the list. Try adding an extra level to your loop and it should work:

```
for x in train['feature']:
    for i in x:
        a = i.split(' ') # this works
```

I'd note that the calls to `split` followed immediately by `join` are a sort of indirect way of replacing spaces with underscores in each string (there are none in your examples, but perhaps there could be in your real data). You could get there more directly by using `str.replace` instead:

```
lambda x: " ".join([i.replace(" ", "_") for i in x])
```